# Make Column Unique Based on Foreign Key in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models `EventLocation` and `EventDepartment`. The models and relationship are shown below:

```
class EventLocation extends Model
{
    public function event_departments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventDepartment::class);
    }

}
```

```
class EventDepartment extends Model
{
    public function event_location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EventLocation::class, 'location_id');
    }
}
```

The migration for the `EventDepartment` contains the `location_id` as a foreign key as shown:

```
Schema::create('event_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();

      $table->string('name');
      $table->foreignId('location_id')->constrained('event_locations');

      $table->softDeletes();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

The issue I am facing now is that, how do I make a column unique in the `EventDepartment` table when creating a new deparment based on the foreign key which is `location_id`?

**i.e An EventDepartment cannot have columns with the same name if they belong to the same EventLocation but i'm able create another EventDepartment with an existing name as long as it belongs to a different EventLocation**

I have tried with this but isn't working:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:event_departments,location_id',
            'location_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $department = EventDepartment::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'location_id' => $request->location_id,
        ]);

        return new EventDepartmentResource($department);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

While creating migration you should set uniqueness by related fields.
In your example it should be by `name` and `location_id`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('event_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->foreignId('location_id')->constrained('event_locations');

        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['name', 'location_id'], 'unique_name_location');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::table('event_departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['location_id']);
        $table->dropUnique('unique_name_location');
    })
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

    Schema::drop('event_departments');
}
```

This will ensure DB level, table's established rules and it is there will not be more than one same name with same location_id. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations).

On PHP level, you have to write your own rule class that will fire and check against rule that DB can accept.

-Make a rule class

```
php artisan make:rule UniqueNameLocationRule
```

-Rule class code

```
public function __construct(string $name, int $locationId)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->locationId = $locationId;
}

public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return !EventDepartment::where([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'location_id' => $this->locationId,
    ])->exists();
}
```

-Validation code

```
'name' => ['bail', 'required', 'min:3', new UniqueNameLocationRule((string)$request->name, (int)$request->location_id)],
'location_id' => ['required', 'exists:event_locations,id'],
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

This should work, please test and tell if there's some error.

Comment: Hi, @Tpojka. Looks like a really nice and well-thought out approach so I upvoted this. However, i'll try to implement during the weekdays and accept as an answer if it works for me. Thanks

Comment: Having on mind your request there from question, I provided what I'd do in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think,in your validation, your uniqiue property is in wrong place. You are checking that 'is "name" variable unique at event_departments table in location_id column' in your code but you don't want to check name. You want to check location_id. If i get your question wrong,I'm sorry.

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'location_id' => 'required|unique:event_departments,location_id',
    ]);
```

Can you try this? Or if you want to check name,try this one;

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:event_departments,name',
        'location_id' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Comment: I am checking for the name. The `EventDepartment` name has to be unique for each `EventLocation` ex an `EventDepartment` can be named "IT Department" and this name can appear twice in the table as long as they belong to different `EventLocation` i.e the `location_id` on the `EventDepartment` table are not the same.